# JSColor not working with <i> element?

Tags: javascript, jscolor

I'm wanting to use JScolor, but I can't seem to be able to get it work when I press on an  element, which kinda defeats the purpose of it. Anyone has a solution?

```
<div class='drag resizable'>
    <ul class='list-inline'>
        <li>
            <textarea class='resizable' type='text'></textarea>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class='buttonDiv'>
                <i class='fa fa-paint-brush fa-lg color' id='rect' aria-hidden='true'></i>
                <br>
                <i class='fa fa-trash fa-lg delete' aria-hidden='true'></i>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a full JSFiddle.

When you click the Paint Brush it's supposed to open the JSColor pallet, but it dosnt, for me it only works on input elements.

https://jsfiddle.net/0vjf9cdz/4/

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: What do you mean by "get it to work when you press on an element"? Can you use example code in your question?

Comment: Define "can't seem to be able to get it work". What happens? Are there any error messages? Also, we can't possibly know the problem without seeing your code.

Comment: Added a JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

This example works fine

```
            <ul>
              <li>
              <button
                class="pincel fa-paint-brush jscolor {valueElement:null,value:'66ccff', styleElement:'rect'}"
               >icon here</button>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <p id="rect" style="border:1px solid gray; width:161px; height:100px;">
            </p>
            <script>
            function update(jscolor) {
                // 'jscolor' instance can be used as a string
                document.getElementById('rect').style.backgroundColor = '#' + jscolor
            }
            </script>a
```

Example here https://jsfiddle.net/rollrodrig/judkgthd/1/

Comment: I know, but that's not what the post is about, I want to be able to click on a <i> element, instead of an input.

Answer (score 0):

Could not let this one go. Was bugging me, lol.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_i.asp

The color attrib is simply not supported on the < i > element...

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean with the consolejs? But yeah my guess would be that it's simply not possible.

Comment: Was answering on my phone, and had a previous code pasted in and then it got posted on pressing enter... Tired sorry. made the edit.